# query a spreadsheet range and find if data is present

Tags: excel

I am trying to query Multiple cells that contain keywords separated by commas i.e

,test1,test2,test3,

I am only trying to search for one word at a time (test1) and then return whether or not the word is included in any of multiple cells.

Ideally I will then be able to pull the word if it is included in a cell and also another value from a neighboring cell. I know this can be done using vba but I need this to be functional on an excel online file.

Is there any way this could be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your data is in range D4:D8, and you search "xyz".
`=COUNTIF(D4:D8,"*xyz*")` should give you the answer.
Perhaps you may have to add a comma here or there, but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a more simple way, especially if you want to keep the data from the next cells over (i.e. if you're testing Column A, and you want other data out of Column B after you're done testing Column A, you might consider this).

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("test1",A2)>0,"YES","NO"),"NO")
```

Here is a screenshot of what I did. After you filter this data, you can continue to parse and manipulate data without a VBA code.[image]